# I need a batch script to strip the leading zero from filenames

Tags: regex, batch-file

Tried a number of way to do this but doesn't give me anywhere near my requriements.

Help and Guidance Please.

What I want to do is run batch file to strip of the leading zeros from the page number at the end of the file name. (_0101)

File name = 05-10-2012#MilitaryPkk-#Books**_0101**.Pdf

_0101 is changed to 101

Output I am looking for is page number goes after the (hyphen) -
New file name = 05-10-2012#MilitaryPkk-101#Books.Pdf

The input file is always prefix with an (underscore) _

So 0101 becomes 101 or 090 become 90, 01 becomes 1.
As you see the its going to be 4, 3 or 2 digits it will in the file name.

The files need to be changed as they arrive into a folder.

I started to look at number count to positions, but not sure if that the best way to do it am a little stuck at the moment suggestion very welcome.

Thanks

JH

Comment: That's going to be really hard to do in a batch file as I'm sure you're discovering. Rather than creating something overly complicated, what about using another tool like PowerShell, a separate executable that you pass the file name to, or Perl?

Comment: Doing this will likely cause the files to appear "out of order" in some tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=#" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *_0*.pdf') do (
  set orig=%%a#%%b#%%c & set pre=%%a#%%b
  for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=_." %%d in ("%%c") do (
    set "str=%%d" & set "str2=%%e" & set "str2=!str2:_=!" 
    Call :StripLeading0 !str2! ret
    set "newfile=!pre!!ret!#!str!.%%f" 
  )
)
set "filename=!newfile!"
echo %filename%
exit /b

:StripLeading0 <input> <return>
setlocal
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=0*" %%A IN ("%1") DO SET Var=%%A
endlocal & set %2=%Var%
```

Comment: I just realized that an asterisk isn't valid in a filename. So, do the asterisks in your filename represent a single character each? If so, I'll have to tweak this answer.

Comment: Hi Matt, the asterisk characters can be left out, infact I will leave them out all together will just cause a problem.

Comment: Hi Matt, if this ('dir /b /a-d *.pdf') was an actual filename set varaiable

Comment: Like set filename=05-10-2012#MilitaryPkk-#Books_0101.Pdf

Comment: Or I have a variable that is passed from another system called %1, so the set filename=%~n1. how would that work in the for /f line with the ('dir /b etc.....

Comment: Here you go. I made some improvements. This should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*_0*.pdf" ') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=*delims=0" %%e IN ("%%b") DO ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%%a_%%b" "%%a_%%e"
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to set your directory as `sourcedir`. I set my current directory (`.`) for testing.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder=%cd%"

    for %%z in ("%folder%\*_0*.pdf"
    ) do for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=#" %%a in ("%%~nz"
    ) do for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%d in ("%%~c"
    ) do for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%f in ("%%~e"
    ) do echo ren "%%~fz" "%%~a#%%~b%%~f#%%~d%%~xz"

    endlocal
```

The `for` loops are :

- `%%z` iterates over the files
- `%%a`-`%%c` the "section" tokens in file name delimited by `#`
- `%%d`-`%%e` the last "section" of the filename splitted by the underscore
- `%%f` the pages number with leading 0 removed

And this, of course, under the assumption that the `#` is a delimiter, and that in the last "section" of the file name the only underscore is the delimiter of the pages number. Under other conditions, the code should be adapted.